# Filter a vector without losing its ownership

Tags: rust

Given a struct as follows:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    id: u32
}

impl Item {
    fn new(id: u32) -> Item {
        Item { id }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to perform filter on a vector of that struct without taking its ownership. The following code won't work because the ownership has been moved:

```
fn main() {
    let items: Vec<Item> = vec![Item::new(1), Item::new(2), Item::new(3)];
    let odd_items: Vec<Item> = items.into_iter()
            .filter(| item | item.id % 2 == 1)
            .collect();
    for i in odd_items.iter() { println!("{:?}", i); }

    for i in items.iter() { println!("{:?}", i); }
}
```

Currently, I have 2 solutions:

1. Having a vector of `&Item` instead of `Item`, however, I find it a bit awkward to start from `Vec<Item>` but end up with `Vec<&Item>`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let items: Vec<Item> = vec![Item::new(1), Item::new(2), Item::new(3)];
    let odd_items: Vec<&Item> = items.iter()
            .filter(| item | item.id % 2 == 1)
            .collect();
    for i in odd_items.iter() { println!("{:?}", i); }

    for i in items.iter() {  println!("{:?}", i); }
}
```

2. Clone an initial vector. I prefer this one but it results in unnecessary cloning, I'd prefer cloning only the items after filitering:

```
fn main() {
    let items: Vec<Item> = vec![Item::new(1), Item::new(2), Item::new(3)];
    let odd_items: Vec<Item> = items.clone()
            .into_iter()
            .filter(| item | item.id % 2 == 1)
            .collect();
    for i in odd_items.iter() { println!("{:?}", i); }

    for i in items.iter() { println!("{:?}", i); }
}
```

I wonder if there is any better way to filter a vector without losing ownership.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Clone an initial vector. I prefer this one but it results in unnecessary cloning, I'd prefer cloning only the items after filtering:

If you want to clone after filtering, you can certainly do so, and it will have the side effect of converting `&Item` to `Item` (which is what `clone()` does by definition):

```
let items: Vec<Item> = vec![Item::new(1), Item::new(2), Item::new(3)];
let odd_items: Vec<Item> = items
    .iter()
    .filter(|item| item.id % 2 == 1)
    .cloned()     // the same as .map(Item::clone)
    .collect();
```

BTW if you can get away with `Vec<&Item>`, that solution might be more efficient because it uses less space (if actual items are larger than a pointer, that is), and it creates `odd_items` as a "view" into `items`. If that's not what you want, then go for the cloning, you'll just need to add `#[derive(Clone)]` to `Item`.

Also note that, despite its bad rap, `clone()` doesn't have to be expensive - "cloning" a `struct` that just contains a `u32` is no more expensive than a `u32` assignment. It's only when the type is large and/or contains heap-allocated data that cloning becomes a thing to shy away from.

Answer (score 2):

In your specific case, you don't actually need to call `collect` as the next `for` loop can use an iterator directly:

```
fn main() {
    let items: Vec<Item> = vec![Item::new(1), Item::new(2), Item::new(3)];
    let odd_items = items.iter().filter(|item| item.id % 2 == 1);

    for i in odd_items {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }

    for i in items.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

With this technique, `odd_items` is a binding to an iterator of `&Item` but type inference hides it (actual type is more complex, as chaining iterators usually results in things like `Filter<Map<Iter<...>>` etc).

The main advantage of doing so is that no Vec is allocated in addition to `items`, and the latter retains ownership.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=94d07035eee776fd1093db4fd491f1a4)